# What faster proxy_pass or redirect to resource

Tags: nginx, performance, proxypass

I transfer my website to new webserver, without assets. I have flolowing links: `site.com/img/image.png` on new website but now, it's got 404 error
also I have old server with images on the same paths, it's look like `old.site.com/img/image.png`

I have two options:

1. use proxy_pass to get images by old paths from `old.site.com`
2. use redirect to redirect queries for images to `old.site.com`

what way is more correct and faster?

Answer (score 0):

proxy_pass is probably the better way to do this as you are presumably updating links and moving images to the new server. A redirect should also return a status response of some kind which could cause problems for search.